# Exception InInitializer Error for public static integer

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a code where I need to call number of Jobs as public static integers from Size.txt file as follows:

```
public class GetJobs {
public static int Jobs = valueN(), inp = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    ........................
    }

public static int valueN(){
            int n;
            File file = new File("C:\\Data\\Size.txt");
            String[] eachLine ;
            int[] MN = new int [inp];
            try{
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);              
                    eachLine = input.nextLine().split("\\s+");      
                    for(int j=0; j<inp;j++){                    
                        MN[j]=Integer.parseInt(eachLine[j]);
                    }   
                    System.out.print("\n");
                input.close();          
                }           
                catch(Exception e){             
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }           
            n=MN[0];
            return n;
    }
```

in Size.txt file the number of Jobs is the first element, the problem is I get an error when I run it. What is the problem?

the error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Please show the *complete* error. "I get an error" doesn't provide much information.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Put that *in the question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public static int Jobs = valueN(), inp = 4;
...
public static int valueN(){
    ...
    int[] MN = new int [inp];
    ...
    n=MN[0];
}
```

When you run `valueN()`, `inp` is still 0. The initialization which will set `inp` to 4 will only occur *after* `Jobs` has been initialized when `valueN()` has returned. So you're creating an empty array. You're then trying to access element 0 of it. (You won't actually have called `Integer.parseInt`, because your `for` loop with `j` will be comparing against `inp`, which is still 0...)

It's not actually clear why you're creating an array at all - you're only returning the first value from the first line anyway, so I suggest you just return that without doing any other parsing. If you *really* want to create an array and parse multiple elements, either change the order of the initialization, or just move `inp` to inside your method. (It's not clear what it's meant to represent anyway...)

(I'd also recommend you stop catching *all* exceptions like that, but that's a different matter.)

Note that running complex code in static initializers is generally a bad idea - it opens you up to this sort of problem. It would almost certainly be cleaner to move the call of `valueN()` to inside `main`.

Comment: I creating an array because I need to get 4 elements in same way. Thank you its work perfectly now

Comment: @John: But you're only returning one of them. What's the point of reading four and then throwing three of them away? If you were returning the array, that would be a different matter...